# C# save entire UI control values to XML

Tags: c#, user-interface, storage

I have a lot of control values in my C# app. I'm wondering if there is a possibility to store and read the entire available control values at once, instead of the code below.

Please note, the code below is only for 1 `groupBox`. I've 8 of them, thus this will generate a lot of code to implement it (8 times the code below).

- groupBox are copies of each other
- the code below works
- I store the data using serializing the configData class (works).

  ```
  private void uiStateWriteToData()
  {
      configData.datSensor4mA1 = (int)uiSensor4mA1.Value;
      configData.datSensor20mA1 = (int)uiSensor20mA1.Value;
      configData.datSensorPidP1 = (int)uiSensorPidP1.Value;
      configData.datSensorPidI1 = (int)uiSensorPidI1.Value;
      configData.datSensorPidD1 = (int)uiSensorPidD1.Value;
      configData.datSensorPidS1 = (int)uiSensorPidS1.Value;
      configData.datSensor1InToOutput1 = uiSensor1Out1.Enabled;
      configData.datSensor1InToOutput2 = uiSensor1Out2.Enabled;
      configData.datSensor1InToOutput3 = uiSensor1Out3.Enabled;
  }


  private void uiStateUpdateFromData()
  {
      uiSensor4mA1.Value = configData.datSensor4mA1;
      uiSensor20mA1.Value = configData.datSensor20mA1;
      uiSensorPidP1.Value = configData.datSensorPidP1;
      uiSensorPidI1.Value = configData.datSensorPidI1;
      uiSensorPidD1.Value = configData.datSensorPidD1;
      uiSensorPidS1.Value = configData.datSensorPidS1;
      uiSensor1Out1.Enabled = configData.datSensor1InToOutput1;
      uiSensor1Out2.Enabled = configData.datSensor1InToOutput2;
      uiSensor1Out3.Enabled = configData.datSensor1InToOutput3;
  }
  ```

Comment: you want to map to a class that you can store but perhaps you can use a mapping framework to do the transformations? Have you looked at AutoMapper?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there are any frameworks that can do that, but maybe you could come up with your own utility that writes control values into xml file based on the control hierarchy, types and names.

Here is how it may look (rather in pseudo-code):

```
private static void WriteControlValuesToXml(XmlDocument document, XmlNode parentNode, Control currentControl)
{
    // if current control is container, writing its children values

    if (currentControl.Controls.Count > 0)
    {
        var addedNode = AddNode(parentNode, currentControl.Name);
        foreach (Control childControl in currentControl.Controls)
            WriteControlValuesToXml(document, addedNode, childControl);
    }
    else
    {
        // if current control is not container, writing control values

        if (currentControl is CheckBox)
        {
            var checkBox = (CheckBox)control;
            AddNode(parentNode, currentControl.Name, "CheckBox", checkBox.Checked);
        }

        if (currentControl is TextBox)
        {
            var textBox = (TextBox)control;
            AddNode(parentNode, currentControl.Name, "TextBox", textBox.Text);
        }

        // ... other known controls
    }
}
```

And following the same logic, you can implement reading the same control values from file.